# Pass a private variable to main() the right way?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public class Test  {
    private static int NN;

    public Test (int N) {
       NN = N;
    }  

   public static void main(String[] args)  {
       Test t = new Test (N);
       int l = NN;
       for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
           // do my loop
       }
   }
}
```

What I want to do is get "N" from the constructor and pass it to a variable I can use in main() BUT:

a) if I do it this way I get a findbugs warning:

```
M D ST_WRITE_TO_STATIC_FROM_INSTANCE_METHOD ST: Write to static field...
```

b) if I *don't* make "NN" static, it doesn't compile.

c) if I write a getter/setter for my private variable (NN) I break the api.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: `Test` is not created, `Test.<init>` will not execute, `main()` will use the default value `0` of `NN`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Uh duh yeah...okay yeah I amended the code above and now see why I'm getting downvoted. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main() is the entry point to your program. There is no object of type Test yet when it is called by the JVM, so the constructor has not been called yet, that is why main() is static, and why any fields it wants to access must also be static.

What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is N, and where does it come from?

If it comes from the command line, then you will find it as a string in the args array. You will then need to convert it to an integer (Integer.valueOf() is suitable if you don't care about error handling), then use it.

Answer (score 1):

The firebug warning `Write to static field...` because you are assigning the `static` variable `NN` in the constructor, to fix it use:

```
public Test (int N) {
   Test.NN = N;
}
```

If you do not want to write `setter/getter` for your `NN` variable; consider using `reflection` to access it in the runtime